# Mongo - Are the ObjectIds of duplicate documents different?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

So I was trying to understand how ObjectId's are created in Mongo, and I found [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid) page describing it:

```
a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
a 5-byte random value, and
a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.
```

Because of the timestamps, does this then mean that even an inserted documents with the same exact contents into the database would get assigned two different `ObjectIds'?

ie. this?

```
db.Collection.insert({'field one' : 'example'} # ObjectID = X
db.Collection.insert({'field one' : 'example'} # ObjectID = Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content of inserted document doesn't affect the generated ObjectId. Even if you generate two ObjectIds within one second, on one machine and within one process, they must be different according to the 3-byte counter, starting with a random value. I tested your example and get ObjectIds, that differs only in last digit that belongs to this counter:

```
import pymongo
from pprint import pprint

client = pymongo.MongoClient()
db = client.db
collection = db.collection

collection.insert_one({'field one' : 'example'}) # ObjectID = X
collection.insert_one({'field one' : 'example'}) # ObjectID = Y 

pprint(list(collection.find()))

# output:
# [{'_id': ObjectId('5c7ee99688f00210d72f224e'), 'field one': 'example'},
#  {'_id': ObjectId('5c7ee99688f00210d72f224f'), 'field one': 'example'}]
```